# How can I animate a UIView's rotation only within a certain degree range?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

In my app, I've got a simulation of an analog readout dial, like you might find on a car dashboard or a control panel. Run the following snippet for an example of what I mean:

```css
svg { height: 100vh; }
#dial {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-dasharray: 405;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
#pointer {
  fill: #FF0000;
  animation: 2s infinite alternate dialrotate;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes dialrotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <circle id="dial" cx="99.5" cy="100.5" r="86"/>
 <polygon id="pointer" points="100.1,25.5 98.2,100 102,100"/>
</svg>
```

<sup>(I'm not using SVGs in my app--I just threw the example together using an SVG because I'm primarily a web developer)</sup>

Here's how I'm animating the dial movement right now:

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.1,
    delay: 0.0,
    options: .curveEaseOut,
    animations: {
        self.dialPointer.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: radians);
    },
    completion: nil
)
```

I want to animate the pointer's direction between the two extremes (270 degrees). But I DON'T want the pointer to rotate across the shorter 90 degree path outside the dial's bounds; i.e. this is WRONG:

```css
svg { height: 100vh; }
#dial {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #CCCCCC;
  stroke-dasharray: 405;
  transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform-origin: center;
}
#pointer {
  fill: #FF0000;
  animation: 2s infinite alternate dialrotate;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes dialrotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(225deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <circle id="dial" cx="99.5" cy="100.5" r="86"/>
  <polygon id="pointer" points="100.1,25.5 98.2,100 102,100"/>
</svg>
```

**How can I force the UIView's rotation to rotate the long way around, instead of rotating over the shortest direction?**

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, by default UIView animation takes the shortest path when interpolating angle values.  You have a couple of options:

1. You can decompose the animation into several shorter steps, or keyframe it.
2. You can use a CABasicAnimation instead and animate your layer's transform using a cumulative animation

Playground example:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
let view = UIView(frame: rect)
let bar = UIView(frame: rect.insetBy(dx: 40, dy: 140))
bar.backgroundColor = .red
view.addSubview(bar)

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
animation.toValue = 1.25 * CGFloat.pi
animation.isCumulative = true
animation.duration = 5
bar.layer.add(animation, forKey: "spin")
bar.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(1.25 * CGFloat.pi, 0, 0, 1)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: Note that `transform.rotation` means the same as `transform.rotation.z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
UIView.animate(
    withDuration: 0.1,
    delay: 0.0,
    options: .curveEaseOut,
    animations: {
        if radians > CGFloat.pi {
            self.dialPointer.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi);
        }
        self.dialPointer.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: radians);
    },
    completion: nil
)
```